# Get object at the start of view swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, view

I have a view and I want to load the data from the database from the **start** of the view, because I want to edit the profile of my user.
So whenever I will start the my view, the data will be loaded.
This is my code but it gives me an exception on the TextField.

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State var  myUser = User()
    var repo = myRepo()

     var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("edit the name")){
                    TextField("Nume produs", text: self.myUser.name) //IT DOES NOT WORK HERE
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(){
            getMyUser()    
        }

    func getMyUser(){
        Task{
            do{
                try await repo.getUserProfile().watch(block: {item in
                    self.myUser = item as! User
                })
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This just does not work when I put as a TextField**
What is the best way to have the data of my object (myUser) right away on the start of the view?

Comment: You can't have it right away, you can handle the delay by showing a `ProgressView` while it is loading or disabling, or show some other animation.

Comment: have you tried using `TextField("Nume produs", text: $myUser.name)` , note the `$`. You need to have a `Binding<String>` for `TextField text`. What error do you get? Also show the code for `User`

Comment: yes I ve tried with $ and it breaks as well when I open the view, the exception: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1`

Comment: I think it is because the text field **expects** to have a value right away, but it does not have at the start, and then it breaks, I am correct?

Comment: @loremipsum how do I add that on my own code?

Comment: In your `User` that you don't show, use `var name: String = ""`, then as you say, it will have something 
at the start. Note that you still have to use `TextField("Nume produs", text: $myUser.name)` with the `$`

Comment: I added this, and my field is var name: String = "" as you said, but it still breaks with that exception

Comment: I don’t have enough information to correct the code but you need to convert “watch” to a concurrent type. Closures just don’t have the capability of “holding their spot” in an actor, Task would get terminated because it doesn’t know to when to await/return. Watch “Meet async/await” so you can learn how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just init the `String` as empty and create the `@Binding` like so:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct ProfileView: View {
        @State var  myUser = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Form{
                    Section(header: Text("edit the name")){
                        TextField("Nume produs", text: $myUser) //IT DOES NOT WORK HERE
                    }
                }
            }.onAppear(){
                getMyUser()
            }
        }
        
        func getMyUser() {
            Task{
                do{
                    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3_000_000_000)
                    
                    myUser = "HELLO"
                }catch{
                    print("error")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]